# Write text to image in C++

Tags: java, c++, image, libraries

Is there any C++ libraries that support writing text onto images, like `awt` in Java?

What I want is to create an image, then write a string to it (with pre-defined font style and size) and finally save it as, for example, .bmp image. But I only know C/C++ at the moment.

Can anyone shed some light on my matter before I switch to Java?

Comment: take a look at opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens of libraries for manipulating images and adding text on them. I'd recommend looking at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) and [LibGD](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/). Both have C/C++ API.

Comment: I decided to switch to Java already. But u answered my question. Tnx